# How to print to bash file descriptors in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to open a file descriptor in bash an later output to that from within `awk`.

Consider the following `bash` script:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec 6>&1
awk 'BEGIN{print "FD1" >/dev/fd/1 ; print "FD6" >/dev/fd/6 }'
exec 6>&-
```

The problem is that the above is outputting nothing at all.
I use Gnu Awk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put double quotes around the special device file:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "FD1" >"/dev/fd/1" ; print "FD6" >"/dev/fd/6" }'
```

See third from last sentence [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Special-FD.html) for explanation.