# How can I split the stdout from a program into two (multiple) streams based on some grep commands?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a program that dumps different tabular data formats (number of columns and column types) to `stdout`; ideally, I want to run the program only once and split `stdout` into multiple streams, so I can read the CSVs directly from the streams, without attempting to homogenize the tabular data or run the program multiple times.

Comment: The easy way is to save the output in a file or variable. Then you can process that multiple times to get rows that depend on different criteria.

Comment: The hard way is to use multiple coprocesses. The main script process writes each stream to the FD corresponding to the appropriate coprocess.

Comment: See the [Coprocesses](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html) section of the Bash manual.

Comment: You can trivially write `awk` that writes data to a different file descriptor based on the number of fields in a line, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22041383/2836621

Comment: Basically, you write a script, which in a loop reads from stdin line by line, and based on each line, writes the line to one of two output channels (for instance, two files; or one to stdout and the other to stderr). Then you redirect the stdout of your program to your script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a smallish number of outputs, you could use an awk that supports `/dev/fd/#` instead of grep:

```
dump_program |
awk '
    /regex1/ { print > "/dev/fd/1" }
    /regex2/ { print > "/dev/fd/2" }
    /regex3/ { print > "/dev/fd/3" }
    # ...
' \
    1> >( process1 ) \
    2> >( process2 ) \
    3> >( process3 ) \
;
```

Comment: might be better to only use fd > 2 so that stdout and stderr are still available. also stderr is usually unbuffered unlike other fd

Answer (score 3):

This is a variation of the excellent answer by @jhnc.  It avoids explicit manipulation of file descriptors and the use of '/dev/fd':

```
dump_program |
    awk '
        BEGIN {psfile1=ARGV[1]; psfile2=ARGV[2]; psfile3=ARGV[3]; delete ARGV}
        /regex1/ { print > psfile1 }
        /regex2/ { print > psfile2 }
        /regex3/ { print > psfile3 }
    ' >(process1) >(process2) >(process3)
```

- See [Awk script: How to prevent ARGV from being treated as an input file name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18825007/4154375) for information about the use of `ARGV` in `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this construct:

```
myprog | tee >( grep COND1 > out1) >( grep COND2 > out2) | grep COND3 > out3
```

`COND*` are the grep conditions and `out*` the output files.

Comment: Running three copies of grep is certainly less efficient than one copy of awk, though.